# Issue with displaying a Label in a FlexTable

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I execute the code below the image is displayed however the name is not displayed below it. The Window.alert does display the correct name. So the error must be in the line:

```
flexTable.setWidget(row + 1, col, new Label(youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname()));
```

I have searched for similar code online however I can not find a solution.

I am using Eclipse Juno and GWT.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

```
 public void renderYouthMemberTable(List<YouthMember> youthMemberList) {
    if (youthMemberList != null) {
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        flexTable.clear();
        for (final YouthMember youthMember : youthMemberList) {
            String imageDataString = youthMember.getPhotograph();

            //Display each image with the name under it.
            Image image = new Image(imageDataString);

            flexTable.setWidget(row, col, image);
            flexTable.setWidget(row + 1, col, new Label(youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname()));
            Window.alert("Name " + youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname());

            //Add click handler
            image.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                    // Do something - Go to next view passing the ID
                    //returnID = youthMember.getId();
                    //Window.alert("returnID = " + returnID);
                    //navHandler.go(AwardOverview);
                    Window.alert("Picture clicked");
                }
            });

            //Go to next column and if the end of the columns
            //drop two rows and go to the first column
            col = col + 1;
            if (col > 7) {
                row = row + 2;
                col = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The answer is that the name was displayed. However, it was not visible. So I changed the code to (the change is after the image display - which always worked):

```
flexTable.setWidget(row, col, image);
            Label lblYMname = new Label (youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname());
            lblYMname.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
            lblYMname.setWidth("151px");
            flexTable.setWidget(row + 1, col, lblYMname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the name was displayed. However, it was not visible. So I changed the code to (the change is after the image display - which always worked):

```
flexTable.setWidget(row, col, image);
        Label lblYMname = new Label (youthMember.getSurname() + ", " + youthMember.getFirstname());
        lblYMname.setStyleName("gwt-Label-Login");
        lblYMname.setWidth("151px");
        flexTable.setWidget(row + 1, col, lblYMname);
```